# How do I input an unicode character in any X windows' text field properly using python?

Tags: python, xlib, xorg

I have developed a chinese input program, and it is just simply using tkinter and pyxhook. (I won't make it an ibus extension as it's too painful and nowhere to start)

For the text input part, I have been struggling because I can't find a decent way to input character that my python program can only call `xdotool type {char}` all the time.

Calling xdotool's performance is barely acceptable, it just sometimes lose characters (5% chance I have to re-type a character).

Since a firefox-developer's update, the python program eats the characters all the time (95%) when typing on firefox. Whenever I have to type in chinese, I can only type on text editor and copy-paste to firefox.

Ok, the question is, is there anyway for a python program to type chinese in a X window decently, rather than calling xdotool all the time? (Perhaps xlib?)

Answer (score 3):

How do you pass the characters? How is the input encoded? `xdotool` accepts inputs for [(U+23478)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23478/index.htm) in the following format:

```
xdotool key U23478
```

I would be surprised if `xdotool` would "loose" the input. I would expect strange behaviour on `xdotool key`  though.

Comment: That helped a bit, the input is more unlikely to lose by change from "type" to "key".

Comment: And `type` with the same notation still doesn't work?

Comment: With `type`, it will be very likely for xdotool to lose tge input on firefox. Also, xdotool's performance is kind of bad, don't know whether it's gnome's problem.

Comment: Confirmed, basically gnome caused the lag. Tested on Openbox (archbang on kvm), the performance is better than bare arch + gnome.